# Arules - introducing new measure

Tags: r, arules

I am new to R. I am trying to run Arules for titanic data. I am using the following code:

```
library(arules)
library(plyr)
rules<-apriori(titanic.raw)
inspect(rules)
rules <- apriori(titanic.raw,
                  parameter = list(minlen=2, supp=0.005, conf=0.8),
                  appearance = list(rhs=c("Survived=No", "Survived=Yes"),
                                     default="lhs"),
                  control = list(verbose=F))
inspect(rules)
quality(rules)$rec<- support(rules,titanic.raw)/count(rhs)
```

I am able to get the result. However, I need to introduce one more measure apart from support,confidence & lift i.e. rec = Support/(total no of target instances), written in the last piece of code.

I think that I am going wrong in writing it. Could any of the folks help and guide me through it? would really appreciate it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide `titanic.raw` to make your example reproducible. `dput(titanic.raw)` might help.

Comment: Hi Luke, Thanks for looking into it. I am sharing the link to the titanic.raw data set.

Comment: The data can be found at the below link: http://www.rdatamining.com/data

Comment: I am not quite sure what you want to count in the rhs of the rule.

Comment: its the number of target instances as per the formula .